# Prioritize intents in IntentService

Tags: android, service, intentservice, android-intentservice, android-webservice

Here is what I do now:

1. I have a service that runs in the background and reads user location. Each time a valid location is read (there are some parameters like distance and time) an IntentService is started to send that location to a web server
2. The app, that uses the tracking service, also has some web calls, depending on what options the user presses. Right now, the app simply calls the web service in a asynctask.

Some code:
The location service fires the IntentService, each time a good location is received, like this:

```
Intent intentService = new Intent(LocationLoggerService.this, LocationManagerIntentService.class);
intentService.putExtra(Constants.MESSAGE_LOCATION, readLocation);
startService(intentService);
```

The intentservice processes the intent:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     LocationInfo location = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(Constants.MESSAGE_LOCATION);
   .... //Do the web call and broadcast result to app
}
```

Here are the changes I need to make:

1. The IntentService and the app must not call web server in the same time. As the implementation is made now, this is not possible, as they act independent. I was thinking of passing all the web calls from the app, to the IntentService by creating intents for all of them. Would this work? In case that there was a location web sending, a new intent from an app call would be put in queue and executed right after current call?
2. If there are multiple location sending in queue because of low network speed, the app call, needs to be put in front of queue and not wait for all existing intents to finish, just for the current one. Is there a way to put an intent on top of queue?

Thank you.

Later edit:

Here are the changes I've made.

1. Created a custom intent service

> ```
> public abstract class PriorityIntentService extends Service {
>       private final AtomicInteger     intentsCount    = new AtomicInteger();
>
>   protected void intentFinished() {
>       intentsCount.decrementAndGet();
>   }
>
>   private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
>       public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
>           super(looper);
>       }
>
>       public final boolean sendPriorityMessage(Message msg) {
>
>           intentsCount.incrementAndGet();
>
>           int priority = msg.arg2;
>
>           if (priority == 0) {
>               return sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(msg);
>           } else {
>               return sendMessage(msg);
>           }
>
>       }
>
>       @Override
>       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
>           onHandleIntent((Intent) msg.obj);
>
>           if (intentsCount.get() == 0) {
>               // stopSelf(msg.arg1);
>               stopSelf();
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
>
>   @Override
>   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
>
>       Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
>       msg.arg1 = startId;
>       msg.obj = intent;
>
>       if (intent.getExtras().getInt(Constants.MESSAGE_PRIORITY) == 0) {
>           msg.arg2 = 0;
>       } else {
>           msg.arg2 = 1;
>       }
>
>       mServiceHandler.sendPriorityMessage(msg);
>       // mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
>   }
> }
> ```

2. And the other service:

> ```
> public class LocationManagerIntentService extends PriorityIntentService {
>
>     @Override
>       protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
>
>       intentFinished();
>       }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible because of the way `IntentService` is built, but, `IntentService` is a **very** simple code and is open source, so you can just create your own version of it with a few modifications.

The original code is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java).

In the `onCreate()` method you can see where `Service` creates a `HandlerThread` and a `Handler` that dispatch all the `onHandleIntent` calls.

So all you have to do is:

- Create a Singleton `HandlerThread` and `Handler` for your whole application to use. Every network call or `CustomIntentService` should call this single `Handler`. That's part 1. You just forced all the network calls to never happen concurrently.
- Now that you have all the calls through the same Thread and Handler, it's just a matter of calling [Handler.postAtFrontOfQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtFrontOfQueue(java.lang.Runnable)) to prioritize certain executions.

Happy coding.

**Edit:**

- `HandlerThread`: a thread that doesn't finish. It has a "looper" that keeps the thread alive. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html
- `Handler`: a "handle" to a thread that contains a "looper". Through this handle any thread can send `messages` or `runnables` to this handle thread. The messages will be executed on the handle `handleMessage(Message)` callback and `Runnables` will have the `run()` method executed.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
- All this Handler stuff gets funneled to the `MessageQueue` which is unique for each looper/thread. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html

**New edit:**

The reason it's not executing is here:

```
stopSelf(msg.arg1);
```

This stops the service once all the messages being executed, check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelfResult%28int%29):

> Stop the service if the most recent time it was started was `startId`.
>   This is the same as calling `stopService(Intent)` for this particular
>   service but allows you to safely avoid stopping if there is a start
>   request from a client that you haven't yet seen in `onStart(Intent,
>   int)`.
>
> Be careful about ordering of your calls to this function. If you call
>   this function with the most-recently received ID before you have
>   called it for previously received IDs, the service will be immediately
>   stopped anyway. If you may end up processing IDs out of order (such as
>   by dispatching them on separate threads), then you are responsible for
>   stopping them in the same order you received them.

So you'll have to find a different way of checking if all the messages have been executed before finishing. Maybe an [`AtomicInt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) counting the number of messages in the queue, or a map to hold the `startId`.

Comment: Thank you @Budius, I don't fully understand what you meant but I will closely investigate what you say there and try to implement it.

Comment: I put some extra comments and extra links on what each object does. It's the base for Android threading model. In my opinion regardless of the current code you're trying to do, it's very important to understand those concepts to be able to proper handle threading. PS.: don't forget to check the executors too: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: please take a look on what I did so far and give your thoughts. Thank you, really appreciate it.

Comment: please take a look on the new edit I made on my answer

Comment: I really don't understand. Isn't `IntentService` supposed to process all the intents it receives in a queue? So if I send 5 intents, all should be executed one after another. From what I see, it only takes care of first intent, the rest are ignored which does not make any sense to me.

Comment: yes, but after the queue is empty the service have to stop. And on `IntentService` it stops by calling `stopSelf(int)` the int is the `startId` received on the last call to `start(Intent, int)`. All this makes the normal `IntentService` only stop after the last intent on the queue. Problem is that on your custom service, the order the Intents are received is not the same as they are processed. So you have to find a new way to track the queue status, to know when to stop the service.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do this.. I'll dig a bit more. Thanks for your precious time and info.

Comment: quick answer: remove `stopSelf(msg.arg1);` and find another way to call `stopSelf();` after ALL the work is done.

Comment: I wonder if I store in a variable in CustomIntentService the last startId, put this startId to each intent as an extra and then on LocationManagerIntentService after onHandleIntent if both values are the same, call stopSelf...

Comment: stopping the service is responsibility of the `CustomIntentService` (which I would rename to `PriorityIntentService`). I would suggest using an `AtomicInteger` (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and simply increment and decrement the value. If `value == 0` the queue is empty and the service can stop.

Comment: You say something like this: having `public static AtomicInt` in `PriorityIntentService` which gets incremented each time `sendPriorityMessage` is called. Then from my IntentService after a handle is executed, decrement this value? Where should I check if `value==0` on `handleMessage` ?

Comment: yes. Except I wouldn't make it `static`, just a `private final AtomicInt`

Comment: I've updated my solution. it does seem to work from my preliminary testing. Do you see any problem with my implementation ? Thanks

Comment: hehehehe... I feel like I'm doing code review here with you. Imagine you have 10 different classes extending `PriorityIntentService`, and then in one of them you forget to call `intentFinished()` this would cause a problem right? So why not, remove method `intentFinished();` and replace the `if (intentsCount.get() == 0) {` bit with `if (decrementAndGet.get() == 0) {`.